# communication between winros and ubuntu didn't work

Tags: ros, multiple, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I was testing the ROS communication between a windows vista laptop running winros,
and a ubuntu desktop, based on instructions on [this wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).

I run the talker.py node on one machine and listener.py node on the other. I can see the node and topic list on the listener side in command line. It seems fine. But the listener node is not picking up the message on /talker topic.

I tried the network communication tutorial on ubuntu machines and had no problems.
So I suspect that the problem is on the windows side.(It works if I run talker and listener nodes both on winros).

Does anyone know what went wrong here?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55906/communication-between-winros-and-ubuntu-didn%27t-work/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the [network setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup). I suspect, you'll need to set ROS_IP.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2013-02-25**:
thanks, that solved the problem